# In pandas, how to create dataframe indexed by id and with columns with separate content for each appearance?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, separator, identity-column

In Python 3 and pandas I have the dataframe:

```
comps.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 62679 entries, 0 to 62678
Data columns (total 39 columns):
cnpj                           62679 non-null object
razao_social                   62679 non-null object
nome_fantasia                  36573 non-null object
nome_socio                     62679 non-null object
cnpj_cpf_do_socio              62679 non-null object
```

Column (cnpj) has unique company identifier codes. And the columns (nome_socio) have the names of people related to the companies and the column (cnpj_cpf_do_socio) the identification codes of these people

So the code in (cnpj) can be repeated many lines, according to the number of people related. For example:

```
cnpj            nome_socio  cnpj_cpf_do_socio 
12345678901234  Paul JR.    987654321
12345678901234  Paul SR.    987665656
12345678901234  Mary Tree   987651213
12345678901234  Paula Sims  987652328
78889098898085  Vitor Moon  558900690
78889098898085  Sheila Kerr 546656588
```

The other columns (razao_social) and (nome_fantasia) are also repeated, are the names of the companies

So I would like to create a new dataframe that only has each code (cnpj) on each line, and the respective names (razao_social) and (nome_fantasia). And all (nome_socio) and (cnpj_cpf_do_socio) corresponding all on the same line, but separated by ";"

Something like:

```
cnpj            razao_social    nome_fantasia   all_names                               all_ids_names
12345678901234  Company 1       Zebra           Paul JR.;Paul SR.;Mary Tree;Paula Sims  987654321;987665656;987651213;987652328
78889098898085  Company 2       All Shops       Vitor Moon;Sheila Kerr                  558900690;546656588
```

Please, does anyone know how I can create this new dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby`, `agg` and do something like:

```
df1 = (df
      .groupby(['cnpj','razao_social', 'nome_fantasia'])
      .agg({'nome_socio': lambda x: ';'.join(list(x)),
            'cnpj_cpf_do_socio': lambda x: ';'.join(list(map(str, x)))})
      .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `pivot_table`, something like this:

```
funcs = {"razao_social": lambda x: x, "nome_fantasia": lambda x: x,
         "nome_socio": lambda x: ";".join(x), "cnpj_cpf_do_socio": lambda x: ";".join(x)}
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index="cnpj", aggfunc=funcs)
```

Then create `all_names`:

```
pivot["all_names"] = pivot["nome_socio"].str.cat(pivot["cnpj_cpf_do_socio"], sep=";")
```